# Unable to set jsp form values to class variables

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, getter-setter

When I try to fetch the values from class, which were set in jsp, null is shown.

Following error is observed in dev mode:

> ERROR ParametersInterceptor Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
>       Unexpected Exception caught setting 'name' on 'class org.ravi.EmployeeAction: Error setting expression 'name' with value 't'

Below are my various pages

struts.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="addEmployeeAction" class="org.ravi.EmployeeAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <result name="success">/Add.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="EmployeeAction" class="org.ravi.EmployeeAction" method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

index.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

    <s:form action="Add.jsp" name="addForm">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>EmpID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>DoB</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><input type="radio" name="record"
                    onClick="radioValidate(this, 'record')" value="%{var}">
                </th>
                <th><s:property value="empid"/></th>
                <th><s:property value="name"/></th>
                <th><s:property value="city"/></th>
                <th><s:property value="dob"/></th>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Add.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add New User</h1>
    <s:form action="EmployeeAction" >
    <s:textfield label="Emp Id" name="empid" />
    <s:textfield label="Name" name="name" />
    <s:textfield label="City" name="city" />
    <s:textfield label="DoB" name="dob" />          
    <s:submit />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

EmployeeAction.java

```
package org.ravi;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Employee> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8136507522861159378L;

    private Employee employee=new Employee();

    public Employee getEmployee()
    {
        return employee;

    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        this.employee=employee;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception 
    {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getModel() 
    {
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package org.ravi;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable{

     static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     private String empid;
     private String name;
     private String city;
     private String dob;

    public void setempid(String empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setcity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setdob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getempid() {
        return this.empid;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getcity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public String getdob() {
        return this.dob;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're committing several errors, the worst is that

- you're generating getters and setters manually (a lot of useless work), and you're also doing it wrongly: the first letter of the variable name must be capitalized:

  > `setName(` instead of `setname(` for variable `name`.

  You *should* (for simplicity and consistency) also do it for every word of your variables with more than one word:

  > `setEmpId(` for variable `empId`.

  You should also consider avoiding the redundancy when possible. If you have an ID field on a class `Employee`, just call it `id`, not `empId`... if it's inside Emp, it's obvious it's emp id and not something else id.
- Use `ModelDriven` only if you enjoy pain. For any other purpose, it is as useful as a sausage in your pocket when facing a pack of hungry stray dogs.
- Use the HTML5 DTD `<!DOCTYPE html>` also if you're targeting old browsers, there's no need to use `4.01` nowadays.
- Never call JSPs directly like you do in your first form, always pass through actions first.

Start with this. There's plenty more.

---

**Must read**

- [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)
- [Java Beans specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html)

Comment: And the interceptor stack.

Comment: This need `Bean` and `CamelCase` link to be complete.

Comment: I've added them so many times :/ I've done it now too @AxelH, for the sake of completeness... :)

Comment: Sorry I was direct ... this was of course a proposition :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrea for your answer and very insightful inputs. Have noted them all. Will surely help.

Comment: As suggested by AleksandrM, you're using only two interceptors for your actions. Unless you know exactly what to do, the best choice is to use the defaultStack interceptor stack for now

Comment: I tried all the things mentioned, and it worked after I generated getters and setters in _EmployeeAction_ class itself.

Comment: Yes, because for this simple case, only Parameters and ModelDriven interceptors are needed. But if you add a prepare method, you'll need the Prepare interceptor, if you try putting some validation you'll need the Validation interceptor, if there's a conversion error you'll need the ConversionErrors and Workflow interceptors, etc... you're giving up the majority of the framework mechanisms in this simple case,and it's working as is because it has almost nothing in it. Your webapp will grow and you'll need a lot of things you won't know you've removed by avoiding the defaultStack. Put it back ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
   public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

You need to name all of these properly, ie setName(String name)
same for setEmpId and so on. Struts cannot find your getters/setters because they don't follow naming conventions.